# Error -the requested personality Delphi.Personality is not available

Tags: delphi-11-alexandria

I had the Community Edition of Delphi 10.4 Sydney. The key expired, so I registered for a Community Edition license for Delphi 11.3 Alexandria.

I received one, installed Delphi 11 CE, but I keep on receiving the next message when trying to open the projects that I developed in Delphi 10 CE:

> The project can not be loaded because the required personality Delphi.Personality is not available.

When installing, I also had the error from the image, but Delphi opened.

I uninstalled and deleted all Embarcadero files, and reinstalled everything again, but still the same issues.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "*I also had the error from the image*" - there is no image provided.

Comment: It seems like the image did not upload. I can't ulpoad it know. The image with the error that appears after I selected several sub-packages to be installed with the delphi windows platform is "Rad Studio 11 - Operation error - Canot load data from the server: invalid property value". Considering that is nothing I can't do, I hit the close button and then Delphi 11 opens and when trying to open an application developed in Delphi 10.4 I get the previous mentioned error "The project can not be loaded because the required personality Delphi.Personality is not available."

Comment: I have the same issue every day. An "error from image the image" is irrelevant to this issue.